# Modifying ASP.NET Membership Schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

So I'm using Forms Authentication on my site, and I've set up all the tables and stored procedures in SQL Server. The only thing is, I really don't think I need all these tables, and I'm not a big fan of the table names either.

For instance, I'm using the authentication for employees, so it would be nice to change the table name from "aspnet_Users" to "Employees". And I don't really need the Personalization tables. But I don't know if that would break anything.

Is it possible to modify/delete tables and stored procedures without messing everything up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom forms authentication in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586891/custom-forms-authentication-in-mvc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steven, I take it you ran the `aspnet_regsql.exe` command line tool to add these database objects? Alternatively, you can add just the necessary tables/views/stored procedures for different parts of Membership by running the applicable SQL scripts, which you'll find in the `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\version` folder (where *version* is the .NET version you are using, like **v4.0.30319**).

There you'll find files named `InstallCommon.sql`, `InstallMembership.sql`, `InstallRoles.sql`, `InstallProfile.sql`, `InstallSqlState.sql`, and so on. You'll need to run `InstallCommon.sql` and then just those other files you need. So if you need just Membership and Roles, you'd run `InstallCommon.sql`, `InstallMembership.sql`, and `InstallRoles.sql`. In this way your database would not include the tables/views/sprocs for profile, SQL state, and so on.

All that being said, I'd just leave in all of the database objects that ASP.NET added. It's probably more work than it's worth to add just the subset of interest and, who knows, you may need to implement profile or Health Monitoring later so why not have these other database objects in place and
ready to go.

And to answer your first question - No, there is no way to change the table name from `aspnet_Users` to `Employees`. However, it's not uncommon to create your own table (perhaps called `Employees`) that stores information about an employee. This table, then, would have a foreign key back to `aspnet_Users` that links an employee to a particular login account. See [Storing Additional User Information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) for a look at how this can be accomplished.

Happy Programming!

Comment: Thanks Scott, that link is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a simple [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)?

Edit: No, the default providers expect that schema.  I would not recommend modifying it.

Comment: If it's not a question, but an answer it's right. This is the only possible method, but it's quite a big task.

Comment: No, it's an answer.. writing Providers isn't that difficult at all once you find one or two samples (and there are plenty of them out there) to help you along..

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just leaving the authentication stuff in it's own database?

Answer (score 1):

You can change all references to aspnet_Users to Employees in the .sql scripts mentioned by Scott Mitchell but it isn't recommended. The Membership / Roles API uses stored procs. So if you don't change storedProc names you will be fine.

The issues might be if any future changes to membership / Roles providers and/or API.

Also say in future you need to give access to some users who are not the Employees, the renaming will lose its meaning.